# Permission denied when running fs-plus module

Tags: node.js, electron, atom-editor

I'm writing package for [Atom editor](https://atom.io).

Can anyone help with `persmission denied` error I get when using [fs-plus](https://github.com/atom/fs-plus) `makeTree` method in my package when running it on Mac? No errors on Windows.
I use fs-plus, the same module that Atom uses in its [tree-view](https://github.com/atom/tree-view) package (and tree-view works on Mac).

UPD: Adding screenshot, and some code:

[image: When I say Atom uses tree-view plugin and it works I mean this:]

New Folder option shown on the picture is implemented using the same module - fs-plus, and it works on Mac. I use just the same module, and the same method (fs-plus.makeTree) to create directory, but my implementation fails with `Permission denied error`.

My code:

```
import util from 'util';
import { sep } from 'path';
import fs from 'fs-plus';


const makeTreeAsync = util.promisify(fs.makeTree);
createTutorial(data) {
    const { initialPath } = this;
    const { fileName } = data;
    const filePath = `${initialPath}${sep}${fileName}${sep}${fileName}.md`;

    return makeTreeAsync(fileName)
      .then(() => writeFileAsync(filePath, this.getContent(data)))
      .then(() => filePath);
  },
```

code from tree-view package:

```
path = require 'path'
fs = require 'fs-plus'
 onConfirm: (newPath) ->
    newPath = newPath.replace(/\s+$/, '') # Remove trailing whitespace
    endsWithDirectorySeparator = newPath[newPath.length - 1] is path.sep
    unless path.isAbsolute(newPath)
      // some path preprocessing

    return unless newPath

    try
      if fs.existsSync(newPath)
        @showError("'#{newPath}' already exists.")
      else if @isCreatingFile
        // some code, we are not interested in as we 're creating directory
      else
        fs.makeTreeSync(newPath)
        @emitter.emit('did-create-directory', newPath)
        @cancel()
    catch error
      @showError("#{error.message}.")
```

Important note: my package is installed manually (copied to `~/<username>/.atom/packages`) and then run `npm i`

Comment: please post the relevant code that generates the issue.

Comment: thanks, I have updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time of debugging, I have a solution. I tried to use native `fs.mkdir` with no luck, but after I added mode as the second argument - it worked.

```
const _0777 = parseInt('0777', 8);
const mode = _0777 & (~process.umask());

fs.mkdir(<folderPath>, mode, () => {});
```

Hope, this will help someone.

Comment: Thanks to @arcanemagus from Atom Slack for help: https://atomio.slack.com/archives/C044E54H0/p1544806223302100?thread_ts=1544805025.301600&cid=C044E54H0